# Identifying path of current JSF / XHTML page

Tags: jsf, path, identifier

I need something that will uniquely identify my JSF (XHTML) page.

I know that I have:

```
String URI = servletRequest.getRequestURI();
```

This gives my full path, but that doesn't help if I use PrettyFaces or any other URL changing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UIViewRoot#getViewId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewId%28%29) for this:

```
String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
```

It's also available in EL as follows:

```
#{view.viewId}
```

Comment: Do I get always the same id even if I change URL with PrettyFaces?