# Conditionally exclude a CSS resource file in template depending on template client

Tags: templates, jsf, resources, facelets, conditional-rendering

In my project, I have a main template page `main_template.xhtml` that has all the resource file includes.

I have a `styles.css` in the main template that contains styling classes of my pages. In one particular page I want to exclude the `styles.css` resource file, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every other UI component, the `<h:outputStylesheet>` also supports the `rendered` attribute. You can grab the current view ID by `UIViewRoot#getViewId()` and just check on that.

So, pieces put together that would look like:

```
<h:outputStylesheet ... rendered="#{view.viewId ne '/specific.xhtml'}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components)
- [Identifying path of current JSF / XHTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371100/identifying-path-of-current-jsf-xhtml-page/)